# How can I append text into detached html

Tags: jquery, append

It seems like this should be super easy, but I have not yet found a way to do it; What I am trying to do is this:

I have some html that came from a service call. The markup has tags in it like p, strong, etc. I am trying to append() a link into the last paragraph before I send the markup to the page (w angular). I have been using jQuery to attempt to get the markup like I want but so far no gold.

My code looks something like this:

```
var intro = row['Introduction']; // from the service call
var contents = jQuery(intro).contents().get(); // get the items within
for (var i = contents.length - 1; i > 0; i--) { // start with the last
  if (jQuery(contents[i]).context.nodeType === 3) { // is it text?
    jQuery('<a class="less">Less</a>').appendTo(contents[i]); // append
    break;
  }        
}
```

This doesn't seem to be having any effect though. When I console.log(contents[i]) after appending, it's still the same. What gives?

For clarification, I have this html coming in the service:

```
console.log(intro);
<p>This is text</p>
<p>This is more text.</p>
<p>And even more here.</p>
```

And this: jQuery(intro).find('p'); gets 0 results!

What am I missing!?

Also, I don't know if this is relevant, however this code is executed within an AngularJS controller.

For a sanity check I tried this on jsfiddle (to make sure I wasn't going bonkers) https://jsfiddle.net/n094LL3s/ Apparently, find does't work with html strings!... -_-

OK, I found out I need to use $.filter('p') not find to get items that are at the root of the set.

Comment: What is the length of contents? Does the loop get executed at all? I mean, you're not doing anything with contents[0], is that by design?

Comment: Contents is variable in length. Usually just a few items: console.log reports one instance as: [text, text, text] . The array can be opened up and each items looks like a typical jQuery item.

The for loop is executed since console.log statements inside it are printed.

Comment: Hm. I think the problem is that you can't append an element to a text node. A little experimenting shows that if you change the condition to `nodetype == 1`, the `a` does get appended. I can't think of a solution though, sorry.

Comment: Yeah its an odd one. Also, console.log(intro); reports stuff like:

<p>Text here</p>
<p>More text</p>

Whereas, console.log(jQuery(intro).find("p"));

Gets no results! How bizzare

Comment: Would it be possible to do `jQuery('<a class="less">Less</a>').appendTo(contents[i].parentNode);`? That works too. Depends on thee structure of your DOM tree though.

Comment: That sort of works. It deft. adds the less link inside the innerHTML of the parent node. Though, I think I may have to refactor this. I need to be able to reconstruct the html after this is done. Getting the contents seems to be a dead end. I need to work with it in it's native format perhaps.

Comment: You could replace the text node with a SPAN that contains the original text followed by the link.

Answer (score 0):

In your case instead of [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) you need to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like this `$(text).filter('p').length`. If you still want to use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) you need to modify your HTML string a bit and put it inside `<div>` element (or any other container), for example like this `text = '<div><p>One</p><p>Two</p><p>Three</p></div>';`

And the reason of this behavior you can find in the [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method description

> Description: Get the **descendants** of each element in the current set of
>   matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Check modified fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pshenichnov/n094LL3s/1/)

Comment: Yeah I figured that out a few hours ago. Though, I decided to go about this a different way entirely.